# How to replace 2 string letters from a String in Dart?

Tags: regex, dart

```
var string = '12345';
```

I want to replace `2` and `4` with `0`, so I tried:

```
var output = string.replaceAll('2, 4', '0') // doesn't work
```

I am not sure if I need to use `RegExp` for this small stuff? Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `RegExp`:

```
final output = string.replaceAll(RegExp(r"[24]"),'0');
```

`[24]` matches any character that is either `2` or `4`.

Comment: What if I want to use string interpolation in it, how will that work? For instance: I want to replace a variable `RegExp(r"[$variable 4]", '0')`

Comment: I am unaccepting this answer because I am not able to use string interpolation part in it.

Comment: This can easily be fixed, just use `RegExp("[${variable}4]", '0')`. I mean the `r` is just denoting a raw string here. 
You are quite new to this site, so maybe check the rules here. Changing the question is highly discouraged, as this makes the answers and efforts potentially useless or inappropriate. Better to ask a new question.

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have upvoted and accepted your answer in the first place, I was very kind to you but thanks for teaching me a lesson :)

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
void main() {
   var string = '12345';
    string = string.replaceAll('2', "0");
    string = string.replaceAll('4', "0");
    print(string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't what I am looking for, I could also have done it 2 times.